# Is it possible to make a post to users feed appear in newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, oauth

A user authenticates to my web page via Facebook. I get an access token that appears to cover posting to her wall. I can successfully do that. However the post is differentiated from something added to the wall by the user directly using the regular Facebook page.

A post of the latter kind appears in the user's news feed, and the news feeds of the user's friends. A post of the former kind does not appear in news feeds. Also it is qualified on the wall as having been written by my app, and there is an option to share it. It seems that it is regarded as something the app wrote, rather than something it wrote on behalf of the user. The user must share it to make it visible. This defeats the point of the action on my page. I want a user their to be able to decide that a post they have made on my page is one that they also want to make on Facebook, without having to visit both pages.

I set permission value:EVERYONE (and I've tried ALL_FRIENDS and PUBLIC).

Is there any way around this, like to get an access token that enables the app to post *on behalf* of the user, rather than *with the permission* of the user - after all the user is logged in at that point both to my page and to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

> Also it is qualified on the wall as having been written by my app, and there is an option to share it. It seems that it is regarded as something the app wrote, rather than something it wrote on behalf of the user.

Postings made through the Graph API always show “via appname”, there’s no way around that.

Comment: I have no objection to that. It's just an illustration that these are a 'different kind' of wall post.

Comment: Also, it is "via" - the implication is that the post originated from the user.

Comment: Not _from_, but _by_ – and _via_ the app.